# Stereoselectivity of Roush crotylboration

Tags: stereochemistry, stereoselectivity, organoboron-compounds

One can use a tartrate derived boronate to enact enantioselective crotyl transfer. Eg in scheme below:
[image]

I do not understand how the stereoselectivity arises. We have a chiral boronate, true, and we have facial selectivity on addition to boron centre. But I don't understand why one face is selected over the other - With one ester group on the ring, I could see that would sterically block one face of the boron centre, but with 2 ester groups it seems that each side of the boron is equally blocked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This figure from this [reference (p. 170).](https://books.google.com/books?isbn=0471465240) might help you visualize things. [image]

As you can see, the stereochemistry is given by electronic repulsion between the carbonyl group and the incoming aldehyde.